# Can I use LATERAL VIEW with STACK function in SparkSQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to unpivot a set of columns from a wide table. I tried to use the below `SQL` syntax which is throwing an error that `Only one generator allowed per select clause but found 2. stack...`

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  STACK(2, 'TRANS1', TRANS1, 'TRANS2', TRANS2) AS (TRANS_TYPE, TRANS_VALUE),
  STACK(2, 'ORD1', ORD1, 'ORD2', ORD2) AS (ORD_TYPE, ORD_VALUE)
FROM TRANS
```

So wanted to check if there is any simple alternative solution to achieve the desired resultset. Is it possible to use the `LATERAL VIEW` with the `STACK` function in SparkSQL?

Existing dataset sample:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Id     |TRANS1 |TRANS2 |ORD1   | ORD2  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|345    |10     |12     |1      |1.2    |
|769    |20     |24     |2      |2.4    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Can be created using below code:

```
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        (345, 10, 12, 1, 1.2),
        (769, 20, 24, 2, 2.4)
    ],
    ('Id','TRANS1','TRANS2','ORD1','ORD2')
)
```

Expected output:

```
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|Id     |TRANS_TYPE    |TRANS_VALUE   |ORD_TYPE      |ORD_VALUE     |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|345    |TRANS1        |10            |ORD1          |1             |
|345    |TRANS2        |12            |ORD2          |1.2           |
|769    |TRANS1        |20            |ORD1          |2             |
|769    |TRANS2        |24            |ORD2          |2.4           |
+-------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the arguments to `stack`. You can replace `string` with `double`/`float` to ensure that the column types are the same.

```
select 
    Id, 
    stack(2, 'trans1', string(trans1), 
             'ord1', string(ord1), 
             'trans2', string(trans2), 
             'ord2', string(ord2)
         ) as (TRANS_TYPE, TRANS_VALUE, ORD_TYPE, ORD_VALUE)
from trans

+---+----------+-----------+--------+---------+
| Id|TRANS_TYPE|TRANS_VALUE|ORD_TYPE|ORD_VALUE|
+---+----------+-----------+--------+---------+
|345|    trans1|         10|    ord1|        1|
|345|    trans2|         12|    ord2|      1.2|
|769|    trans1|         20|    ord1|        2|
|769|    trans2|         24|    ord2|      2.4|
+---+----------+-----------+--------+---------+
```